# Select query using Entity Framework stresses the SQL server

Tags: sql, performance, linq, entity-framework

I'm having insane simple query: It pulls an ID from one table. The implementation is done using EF 3.5.

This query is repeated in a loop, where I collected a ID from a file and do the search in the database. When running this program, the SQL server is stressed like crazy (the processor utilization soars to 100% for all 16 cores).

It looks like the table of this query is completely locked and nobody gets in anymore. I've read about the necessity to use `DbTransaction` (begin transaction, commit) or `TransactionScope`, but the thing is I'm only selecting/reading. 
Also it's one query, which is atomic in itself, so the use of Transaction(Scope) is shady at best.
I did try an implementation, but that doesn't seem to do it.

My (LINQ) query: `Image image = context.Images.First(i => i.ImageUid == identifier)`

Any thoughts on why this is happening? Again I'd like to stress that I'm only selecting/reading records. I don't delete or update records in the database. This is so insanely straight forward that it is frustrating!

For sake of being complete (my attempt at a fix):

```
 // This defaults the isolation level to 'READ COMMITTED' which
 // doesn't lock the table when querying.
 DbTransaction trx = context.Connection.BeginTransaction();
 string isolationLevel = trx.IsolationLevel.ToString();
 Image image = context.Images.First(i => i.ImageUid == identifier);
 trx.Commit();
```

**NEW**: The profiler shows that the Entity framework is doing a SELECT TOP(1) in the image table. This amounts to a MASSIVE amount of reads, hundreds of thousands!
That would suggest that there is no index, but I've looked it up (see comments) and there is one! Also very weird, on the logout, again hundreds of thousands of reads.

I decided to throw out the Entity Framework and do this query using SqlConnection and SqlCommand, but the result is the same!

Next we copied the `sp_executesql` in the management console and found it took an amazing 4 seconds to execute. Doing the query 'direct' gives an instant result.

Something in the `sp_executesql` appears to slow things to a crawl. Any ideas?

Comment: The generated SQL for this should be fairly simple. How many times are you trying to execute this query? How large is the table backing the `Images` collection?  Do you have an index on the ImageUid column?  And finally, can you post both the projected and actual query plan used when executing this query?

Comment: Can you use Profiler to get the actual SQL being created?

Comment: I'm more amazed that you're able to create an image like that.

Comment: Tell me you have an index on Images.ImageUid, otherwise you will have 16 threads running table scans maxing out the CPU.

Comment: The amount of query is restricted by the amount image files that are in a designated folder. This ranges from several thousand to tenths of thousands. The images table contains millions of records. So my first action is to check for an index. I'll also gets the projected and actual query plan.

Comment: The projected and actual plan will be here soon, but the result of the query for the index using `SELECT * 
FROM sys.indexes 
WHERE name='ImageImageUid_idx' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('Image')` shows there is an index on that column.

Comment: My guess would be that @Aron is right, and there is likely no index (and certainly no unique constraint) on `ImageUid`. If the generated sql includes a `TOP (1)` it's because the schema suggests there would be more than one result...  Frank, what is the definition of that index? Is it indexing the correct column? Should this column be unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it... After finding out that sp_executesql was the culprit it became clear.
See http://yasirbam.blogspot.nl/2009/06/spexecutesql-may-cause-slow-perfomance.html

Due to the stupid conversion, the index on the table is NOT used! 
That explains everything visible in the SQL Profiler.

Right now the tool is being tested and it's as fast as lighting!!